# Push notification not working when app is uploaded to App Store

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios for sending push notification for my iOS and Android application.

The notification works fine when I install app using diawi in my iOS device but does not work when I upload the app to App Store and download the app from there.

Also this behaviour is for iOS only, the notifications are working all perfect for the Android platform.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you enabled push notifications for the project in Xcode?

Comment: Yes @miknoup I have enabled